# How to count the lines changed between two commits in gitlab?

Tags: linux, count, line, gitlab

I need to count line changes in the sources in between the particular period of time.

That means, by using the commit Id can I know the line changes count in the source?

I don`t want the line changed per user. I need all the line changes count in between that commits

My gitlab community Edition version is 8.14.3

**Update**

All my sources exist in the mycompany.gitlab.com. How can I achieve my above doubt?

Comment: Gitlab is a service and Git a tool. How is your question specific to Gitlab?

Comment: @ceving I updated in the question. Is this enough or need I explain more?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your git working directory, run:

```
git diff <commit-1> <commit-2> --shortstat
```

You should get an output as following:

```
7 files changed, 39 insertions(+), 107 deletions(-)
```

Comment: I tried the below code. But that was not worked for me.
`git diff <155ee1c3> <bb674347> --shortstat`

I got the exception 
**< was unexpected at this time.**

Comment: Where did I the mistake?

Comment: @Arunald use `git diff 155ee1c3 bb674347 --shortstat` instead. The signs "<>" are only a indication of format.

Comment: I found this answer looking for how to do it with branches. --shortstat works there too. Eg, I can check lines changed on my branch vs. master with `git diff master --shortstat`.

Answer (score 0):

All code referenced can be found in https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html

Get the all the commits (include the **since** and **until** parameters):
`https://gitlab.example.com/api/v3/projects/:project_id/repository/commits`

Response:
[image]

Get the differences of a commit
`https://gitlab.example.com/api/v3/projects/:project_id/repository/commits/:sha/diff`

[image]

Split the above endpoints `diff` field to get the lines changed and sum for each commit.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by using below steps

1. Clone the particular repository to the local machine by using the command **git clone https://gitlab.company.com/testgroup/TestProject1.git**
2. Move the source by using the command **cd foldername**
3. Use the example command to get the line details **git diff --stat**

[image]